# Error with subclass of UITableViewController after changing the class name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I corrected a typo in the class name, and corrected it everywhere necessary (.h,.m, and any class that imported this class).

The application compiles and runs just fine, but when i initiate and push this viewController, the application crashes with this message: "loaded the "OldTracksViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView"

But i do not have a nib file of that name, and never had. I only changed the class name, and it was working fine before that.

I googled it, but i could not find with the exact issue as mine.

Comment: Do you have nib file for that viewController?

Comment: No i only have a viewController which is a subclass of UITableViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clean and clear. Optionally try to delete the DerivedData folder.

clear: **⌘ ⇧ k**

clean: **⌘ ⌥ ⇧ k**

Comment: tried all 3, but no succes. (there was no Derived Data, isn't that strange, since it's a project i've been working on for a while, with many builds etc?)

Comment: By default, the DerivedData folders are stored in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`. You can change this under Xcode settings -> Locations. I store DD relative to the project as it is more easy to use :)